# How to set a character limit and remove characters over that limit excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, csv, validation

I have to provide a CSV file for a telephone system with names and numbers on for a directory. The numbers cannot contain any spaces, and the names must be 20 characters max.

I have a list of names/numbers, but the numbers have spaces and the names are full names. Is there a way to remove characters over the 20 character limit, and remove the blank spaces from the numbers column?

My current CSV file looks like this:

```
+------------ NAME ------------+--- NUMBER ---+
| johnathan ferguson suppliers | 01234 567899 |
| johnathan ferguson suppliers | 01234 567899 |
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer for character limit:

```
=LEFT(CONCATENATE(A1),20)
```

Where A1 is the column with the full text in, and 20 is the character limit now set.

---

answer for removing spaces:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C3," ", "")
```

Where C3 is your phone number with spaces.

Answer (score 5):

For the name column (Let's call it `A`), you can enter the following formula in a new column:

```
=LEFT(A2,20)
```

For the number column (Let's call it `B`), you can enter the following formula in a new column:

```
=REPLACE(B2,6,1,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go to the trouble of writing a macro, simply highlight the `Number` column and press `CTRL` + `F` to bring up the `Find` command.  Click the `Replace` tab then enter a space in the find box and leave the replace with box empty.  Click `Replace All` and all the spaces in your `Number` Column will be removed.  Looks like you have the character limit problem taken care of now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the above solution by Falter in Excel 2010 and got an error.

The correct syntax is:

```
=LEFT(CONCATENATE(A2),30)
```

Comment: Unfortunately through all the edits this answer does not make sense. It seems I also cannot edit myself to restore it, Here is what was expected:
For some people with different regional settings You may try using the above solution by Falter in Excel 2010 and get an error.
with the list separator ';' the correct syntax is:
`=LEFT(CONCATENATE(A1);20)`

Answer (score 0):

```
=LEFT(A1|20)
```

- A1 is the field to be reduced
- 20 specifies the number of characters to be left - all others after 20 shall be removed

It can also be achieved with:

```
=RIGHT(A1,20)
```

where the preceding characters will be removed and the last 20 left in place.

Comment: Is there a localization of Excel in which the pipe symbol `|` works in place of a comma?  (`=LEFT(A1)`) Doesn't work in my U.S. edition of Excel 2007.